# Verify checkbox without using isSelected method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

[image: This is the HTML of the checkbox I'm trying to select]

I can locate the checkbox using xPath but cannot verify if this checkbox is selected using the isSelected() method.

I'm using the xPath as
`//div[@class='Form-field Form-field--spacer']//label[@for='RememberMe']`.
I need to first verify if the checkbox is selected

I tried to verify it using the isSelected() method, but there is no success with it.

Comment: @K. K Are you able to uncheck the checkbox? If yes, Does class value in span changes? Current class value is-"Checkbox is-active"

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath defines a label. Not a check-box. This is why you cannot check if it is selected or not. I would suggest to change your xPath to `//input[@type='checkbox'][@id='RememberMe']`.

Comment: The mentioned xPath is not found, so it is throwing 
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of error.

Comment: @K.K is your check-box displayed (i.e. visible)?

Comment: Yes, by default the checkbox is selected.

Comment: also irrespective of the checkbox checked or unchecked the attribute checked is always set as Checked.

Comment: @K.K the latter is okay. As per specification, `checked` attribute `Specifies that an <input> element should be pre-selected when the page loads (for type="checkbox" or type="radio")`

Comment: I believe you should be checking the value attribute.  In your example HTML code, the value is "true"